# Double status item icons appearing

Tags: cocoa, menuitem, statusbar, menubar

I'm trying to make a simple menu bar only application on xcode 4. Everything actually works, but what I don't understand is that the icon is appearing twice in the menubar. One of the two icons actually works and gives the drop down menu with the working buttons, the other just changes to the highlighted icon images while clicked and goes back when released, without doing anything, not even the drop down menu appears.

This is the code I found and tested out:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib{

//Create the NSStatusBar and set its length
statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength] retain];

//Used to detect where the files are
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

//Allocates and loads the images into the application which will be used for the NSStatusItem
statusImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"icon" ofType:@"png"]];
statusHighlightImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"icon-alt" ofType:@"png"]];

//Sets the images in the NSStatusItem
[statusItem setImage:statusImage];
[statusItem setAlternateImage:statusHighlightImage];

//Tells the NSStatusItem what menu to load
[statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];

//Sets the mouse over text
[statusItem setToolTip:@"My Custom Menu Item"];

//Enables highlighting
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
```

then release the images

```
- (void) dealloc {
//Releases the 2 images we loaded into memory
[statusImage release];
[statusHighlightImage release];
[super dealloc];
```

and the header file:

```
@interface MenuletApp : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
NSWindow *window;

IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;

NSStatusItem *statusItem;
NSImage *statusImage;
NSImage *statusHighlightImage;
```

with an IBAction to log Hello World when one of the items is clicked, and to terminate when the other is clicked.

I used a tutorial meant for XCode 3, so it might be that one of the steps is done differently, but looking at the code I have no idea where the second status item is getting created.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that `-awakeFromNib` is getting called twice? (Try putting a log message in there). Perhaps you have two objects of this class in your xib file?

Also, I'd recommend moving this to [`-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/26/cocoa-tutorial-awakefromnib-vs-applicationdidfinishlaunching/).

Comment: The questioner might also have two objects of this class in two separate nibs (perhaps in the incorrect belief that they will somehow join up and be one object), or have this object loading a nib of its own—in Cocoa, the owner of a nib is also sent an `awakeFromNib` message. Either way, the result is the same and I agree with your proposed solution.

Comment: Moving it to appDidFinishLaunching did it. Thanks!